# Jmap - Error connecting to remote debug server

Tags: jmap

My requirement is to create a dump file of heap memory of a remote server using Jmap.
I did this way.

```
jmap -dump:file=remoteDump.txt,format=b 3104
```

This worked fine as 3104 is the pid of a process from my local machine.
How do I do the same with remote server?
I tried

```
jmap -dump:file=remoteDump.txt,format=b 3104 54.197.228.33:8080
```

But it's failed.
I tried creating a debug server using jsadebugd, as below.
 1.Started rmiregistry

> rmiregistry -J-Xbootclasspath/p:$JAVA_HOME/lib/sa-jdi.jar

2.Ran jsadebugd

```
>jsadebugd 11594 54.197.228.33:9009
```

But the step 2 is throwing the following error:

```
Error attaching to process or starting server: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.D
Exception: Windbg Error: WaitForEvent failed!
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.windbg.WindbgDebuggerLocal.attach0(Na
thod)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.windbg.WindbgDebuggerLocal.attach(Win
ggerLocal.java:152)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attachDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebuggerWin32(HotSpotAgent.j
)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:3
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:313)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.startServer(HotSpotAgent.java:220
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.DebugServer.run(DebugServer.java:106)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.DebugServer.main(DebugServer.java:45)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.jdi.SADebugServer.main(SADebugServer.java:55)
```

Help me get out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can not attach to process could be that it is already attached to some other debuger or executed on other visual machine than your `jmap` is running.

Try to assure that process is not attached to any debuger and you attach to the same VM.